Modifying subset of pandas dataframe also modifies original dataframe
I have pandas DataFrame which I iterate over to get values from two columns (col_1 and col_2). Second column contains lists. What I need to do, is for every value in col_1 get list of values in col_2 and insert value of col_1 into list of col_2 values.
This is how I did it:
import pandas as pd

dict_for_df = {
    "col_1": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "col_2": [["D", "E"], ["F", "H"], ["I", "J"]],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df)
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    col_1_value = df["col_1"][i]
    col_2_list = df["col_2"][i]
    col_2_list.insert(0, col_1_value)

However, insert operation on col_2_list also modifies original df. How to avoid it?
  col_1      col_2
0     A  [A, D, E]
1     B  [B, F, H]
2     C  [C, I, J]

I want to use values in col_2_list in the future, this is why I would like to keep it as separate variable, without modifying original DataFrame.

A possible solution, which uses:

assign to create a new column col_1 in the dataframe df, where each element is converted to a list using the map function.

sum to concatenate the lists in the columns along the rows (axis=1), resulting in a new column col_2.


df['col_2'] = df.assign(col_1 = df['col_1'].map(list)).sum(axis=1)

Output:
  col_1      col_2
0     A  [A, D, E]
1     B  [B, F, H]
2     C  [C, I, J]


I need to keep list of col_2 values as separate variable and do operations with certain list. Is it possible?

I guess so, but to avoid misunderstandings, I suggest you edit your question to indicate what is your expected output.

You can do the following to keep the original col_2 as a separate list: col_2_list = df['col_2'].to_list(). To keep the original col_2 as a column of df: df['col_2_updated'] = df.assign(col_1 = df['col_1'].map(list)).sum(axis=1)

I need to do everything in for loop.
I can not understand, why it is still modifying my original DataFrame. I even tried to create new list within the loop:
col_2_list_new = col_2_list.insert(0, col_1_value)
But it still modifies my col_2_list and df

I think I figured it out. All I had to is to add copy() when determining col_2 variable
import pandas as pd

dict_for_df = {
    "col_1": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "col_2": [["D", "E"], ["F", "H"], ["I", "J"]],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df)
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    col_1_value = df["col_1"][i]
    col_2_list = df["col_2"][i].copy() # Add copy() here
    col_2_list.insert(0, col_1_value)


I would suggest you to use something like this:
import pandas as pd


dict_for_df = {
    "col_1": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "col_2": [["D", "E"], ["F", "H"], ["I", "J"]],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df)

res = df["col_1"].apply(lambda x: list(x)) + df["col_2"]
# Or you can set it as a new col
# df["col_3"] = res

print(res)  # series of lists you want
print(df)  # unmodified

Don't even try to make copies inside loop. This .copy() is deep copy by default and can be expensive. It's better to use more "vectorized" approach.
UPD:
Well, if you are forced to make some operations inside a loop, then I would suggest you to make something like this (I made a little generalization, assuming you have several columns with strings and several columns with lists of strings):
import pandas as pd


dict_for_df = {
    "col_1": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "col_2": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "col_3": [["D", "E"], ["F", "H"], ["I", "J"]],
    "col_4": [["D", "E"], ["F", "H"], ["I", "J"]],
}

# Let's suppose you are forced to create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df)

# But before loop you can extract needed columns to np.arrays/lists
needed_cols_with_strings = ["col_1", "col_2"]
needed_cols_with_list_of_strings = ["col_3", "col_4"]
# This will be list[list[str]] where each row is a "list" of strings
np_strings = df[needed_cols_with_strings].to_numpy().tolist()
# This will be NDArray[list[str]] where each row is a "list" of lists of strings
np_lists_of_strings = df[needed_cols_with_list_of_strings].to_numpy()
# And we can concatenate them in a vectorized way beforehand
# Now it will be NDArray[list[str]] where each row is a "list" of strings
np_list_of_strings = np_lists_of_strings.sum(axis=1)

# Here we will save new strings
new_values = []

# And, suppose, you are forced to use a loop
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    # Just select needed row in each iteration
    curr_strings = np_strings[i]  # list[str]
    curr_lists = np_list_of_strings[i]  # list[str]
    # And then concatenate
    new_val = curr_strings + curr_lists
    new_values.append(new_val)

res = pd.Series(new_values, name="result")
print(res)  # result you want
print(df)  # unchanged


Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm new to Python and pandas and it's kind of confusing how difficult is to create a copy of something.
I'm using copy, because in my case df is small (up to 100 rows).
